# Is there any perform difference on the sequencce of clause "ON" in "JOINs"?

Tags: sql-server

Is there any perform difference on the sequence of clause "ON" in "JOINs"?

```
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON a.id = b.id

SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON b.id = a.id
```

Comment: To clarify: the duplicate is for MySql, but the answers apply equally to Sql Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this simple case not. But to be 100% sure compare execution plan and statistic.

```
SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON
SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON
SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON
SET STATISTICS PROFILE ON
SET STATISTICS XML ON 

<your queries>
```

Comment: thx, I compared both executions, excectly the same result in terms of performance. thx for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not make a difference. You can check this [article: Does order matter in a JOIN clause?](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/02/29/60542.aspx) which provides the details about the same.

> Query #2 produced the exact same execution plan! So, we can conclude
>   from this simple example that the order of tables referenced in the ON
>   clause of a JOIN doesn't affect the performance of a query.